# Reducing image size in an image with dark lines and vast white background

Tags: python, opencv

Is there any algorithm in OpenCv or any other library in Python, that allows me to reduce the image size of a Mechanical drawing from say 8000 x 9000 pixels to 1000 x 1000 pixels, without losing too much of the quality, considering that it is mostly dark lines and a lot of white background.

such as this one :
[Mechanical piece](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih4Ib.jpg)

Comment: and how do you imagine that working? what's wrong with simply storing the full resolution? if you go from 72 megapixels to _one_ megapixel, you necessarily lose a lot of resolution. do you accept that?

Comment: Hello @ChristophRackwitz I was thinking that because it is a lot of whites and black lines, instead of averaging when reducing sizes, the black lines could remain (up to certain dpi) and the white pixels would be first eliminated

Comment: The most sensible thing for such an image would be to store it as a vector image rather than a bitmap. I mean SVG and Inkscape and co. Or, if you only have a bitmap, maybe `potrace` from http://potrace.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I agree with preferring vector formats. depending on the source of the input (a scan/photo?), we're already wrestling in the mud... -- decimating with a `min()` function (which would darken the result, "maintaining" any black pixels) is certainly an acceptable thing to do. there are many ways to achieve that. "blitting" has always had modes where pixels are `or`ed together, and for binary data this gives the same effect. morphology operations (erode) followed by decimation/subsampling can do the same.